# error:Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components

Tags: sdk, flutter

while trying to run a simple code using bloc I weren't able to test it because of that error , and before this it takes a lot of time trying to resolving dependencies and then  post this error :

```
Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.
```

and after running flutter doctor the result is :

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.345], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\aya sisy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.28.1)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the Android Sdk is not found by Flutter.

Did you set the correct ANDROID_HOME environment variable ?

It could also be coming from the path including a space "...\Users\**aya sisy**\AppData\...".

Can you try to move it to another location ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, i ran the same code on another laptop which has no spaces and t has the same error. Also, Do you mean by the correct android home enviroment varibale that the path is the same? Also, I ran so many codes before this code, why does this problem appear only in this code? what caused the path to change/?!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me, except I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, so check the following:

1. The solution was to remove `adb` from `apt` package manager. so see if you accidentally installed `adb` for windows other than the one that come with `android_sdk`.
2. and from the logs you posted, it's clear that there is something wrong inside the `android_sdk` path so try to move it to other directory : for ex `C:\dev\android_sdk` and run the following command

> `flutter config --android-sdk "C:\dev\android_sdk"`

**Hoping that helps.**

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether your 'Project SDK' is set in File -> Project Structure; under the section Project Settings -> Project.
For me, it was not set by default, and setting it solved the problem.

[image: this]